# How can I create a code for T and L Figures but not in a plot?

Tags: plot, rectangles

I am creating a visual search experiment with R. To do this, I created the following figures with a plot: a T-figure and an offset L-figure.

1. I would like to rotate these figures at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees so that I can get every figure at all angles
2. Since I want to use these characters for a visual search experiment, I don't need the characters in a plot, just the code that creates the figure. (because the visual search experiment works in such a way that it shows a different number of figures on a white background)

My code for the figures with plot:
#T
plot(0:10, 0:10,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", bty="n",pch="", ylab="",xlab="", main="", sub="")
rect(5, 5, 7, 5.5, col=1)
rect(5.7, 3.5, 6.3, 5.5, col=1)

#offset L
plot(0:10, 0:10,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", bty="n",pch="", ylab="",xlab="", main="", sub="")
rect(4, 4, 6, 4.5, col=1)
rect(5.5, 3.7, 6, 5.7, col=1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4pn0.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YwN2.png)